# MySQL date between last monday and the next sunday

Tags: mysql

i'm looking to find all records that have a booking date between the previous monday and the next sunday in MySQL.

So far I have:

```
SELECT firstname
     , lastname
     , sessions
     , (SELECT COUNT(memberid) 
          FROM bookings
         WHERE m.memberid = b.memberid  
            and b.date between lastMonday and nextSunday) as sessionsused 
  from members
```

I'm looking what to substitute into the lastmonday and nextsunday

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, could be. How would we know?

Comment: By `lastmonday` do you mean the most recent Monday, or the Monday of the week prior to this week (in which case which day do weeks start on)? ie If today is a Monday, is today `lastmonday` or was `lastmonday` a week ago? If today is a Tuesday is `lastmonday` yesterday or 8 days ago?

Comment: @Strawberry - what do you mean?

Comment: @Matt Well today its Saturday (UK) and tomorrow is Sunday, so i'd be looking for between 5 days ago and tomorrow. Tomorrow i'd be looking for 6 days ago and today (tomorrow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's [`YEARWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function selects a unique value for each week that you can use for comparison. It takes [a second parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) which specifies whether weeks start on Sunday (0) or Monday (1).

```
SELECT COUNT(memberid) 
FROM bookings
WHERE m.memberid = b.memberid  
AND YEARWEEK(b.date, 1) = YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1);
```

This will always select rows where `b.date` is in the current week. For a specific week in the past, change `NOW()` for whatever date expression you require.

For the more generic case where your week does not start on a Sunday or a Monday, you will need some slightly more complicated logic. Here you substitute `@weekday` with the day on which your weeks begin, 2 = Tues, 3 = Wed, 4 = Thu, 5 = Fri, 6 = Sat.

```
SELECT COUNT(memberid) 
FROM bookings
WHERE m.memberid = b.memberid  
AND DATE(b.date)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(NOW()) - @weekday + 7) % 7 DAY)
        AND DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(NOW()) - @weekday + 7) % 7 DAY);
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt will this dynamically change?

Comment: Also, if the day was Monday, would it select today?

Comment: It will always select items from the **current** week, and if today is a Monday, this will select items from today only. I've realised there's a simpler approach though and edited the answer with a new syntax.